# If I don't specify a sentiment model in CoreNLP, what will it use to score the data?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I've been creating sentiment analysis models to use with Stanford CoreNLP, and I've been using the one with the highest F1 score in my java code, like so:

```
props.put("sentiment.model", "/path/to/model-0014-93.73.ser.gz.");
```

But if I remove this line, what does CoreNLP use to score the data? Is there a default coreNLP model that's used if the user does not specify a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no model is given, it'll use the default model included in the release trained on the Stanford Sentiment Treebank: http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/treebank.html